# Как установить шаблон вводимой даты sql.Date?

Tags: java, jsp, дата, format

Добрый день, есть в классе дао метод добавления данных, дата в базу данных добавляется в виде yyyy-MM-dd, пытался сделать в виде dd.MM.yyyy почему то не получается, в таком виде получается только вывести дату, а добавить нет, на jsp делаю так:

`<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${skisql.datez}" />" />`

если сделать так:

`<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" value="${skisql.datez}" />" />`

выдает ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
    controller.SkisqlController.doPost(SkisqlController.java:132)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Судя по всему дата передается как строка, а затем происходит ошибка при разборе. Чтобы сказать где конкретно ошибка покажите: а) как дата передается на сервер (поле `input` в JSP); б) код, который принимает дату в сервлете; в) код, в котором возникает ошибка `SkisqlController.java:132`. P.S. в любых вопросах по исключениям нужно публиковать код, который вызывает исключение.

Comment: а) `<form method="POST" action='SkisqlController' name="frmAddSkisql">
        <table border=1 id="add">
     <tr class="add"><td class="add2"><label>Дата завантаження : </label></td> <td><input type="text" name="datez" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${skisql.datez}" />" /></td></tr> 
     <td class="add2"><input type="submit" value="Сохранить" /></td>
        </table>  
    </form>`  

б,в)  `Date datez = Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("datez"));
        skisql.setDatez(datez);`

Comment: сделал так, вроде все работает `<input type="date" name="datez"`

Comment: Хорошо если все работает. Можете ответить на свой вопрос и отметить ответ как правильный. P.S. Под вопросом есть кнопка «править», вносить изменения в вопрос лучше с ее помощью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно просто использовать в input тип - дата `<input type="date" name="datez"...>`